# AWT ( Abstract Window Toolkit )

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

Which programming language is AWT ( Abstract Window Toolkit ) written in?

Comment: awt usually takes the design from a particular os. so programming language involved is C/C++

Comment: Uh... Java. Which uses JNI to hook into the OS, which would be in C/C++ like @DeepanshuBedi said. -- With that said, you should not be using AWT directly now-days... use either Swing (the replacement for AWT which fixes/improves many things), or JavaFX (the Swing replacemnet) if you are starting out on a new project

Comment: The non-native Java source code is available for you to review at any time, either by searching for the core Java libraries source code online, or on your computer as src.zip if you downloaded it with your Java installation.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , I don't understand how to find the source code , can you help me

Comment: [Google is your friend](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+source+code). First hit. Click on the JDK 8-something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language that has written AWT is C/C++. But you should be using the Swing library since it is an improved version of AWT.

Comment: I just want to know how AWT is built

Comment: It is built in mostly C and C++

Answer (score 1):

AWT stands for Abstract Window Toolkit. AWT requires a native OS object to implement the functionalities. Therefore, AWT components are heavyweight and require more memory space.  AWT components also take time to execute. The number of components available in AWT is minimum. It is necessary to import javax.awt package to develop an AWT based GUI applications.